# Selenium how to display specified string under another specified string?

Tags: python, selenium

I getting names & telephone numbers from a website with python

```
def listToString(s): 
    
    str1 = "" 
    
    for ele in s: 
        str1 += ele + "\n\n"  
    
    return str1 

elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='showLink reveal']")
for element in elem:
    element.click()

name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
names = [elem.get_attribute('innerHTML') for elem in name]
print(listToString(names))

mobile = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@style='display:inline']")
mobiles = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in mobile]
print(listToString(mobiles))
```

This is displays the names & phone numbers but the output is:

```
name: xyz
name: xyz
name: xyz
tel: +12345678910
tel: +12345678910
tel: +12345678910
```

How can I do that the output will be a name and then a phone number like this:

```
name: xyz
tel: +12345678910
name: xyz
tel: +12345678910
name: xyz
tel: +12345678910
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you want to change your `listToString` function to this:

```py
def listToString(lst1, lst2):
    result = [None]*(len(lst1)+len(lst2))
    result[::2] = lst1
    result[1::2] = lst2

    str1 = "" 
    
    for ele in result: 
        str1 += ele + "\n\n"  
    
    return str1
```

Basically, the added code creates a new, alternating list, which alternates between the values in lst1, and lst2. Then, the rest of your code stays the same to turn this new list into a string.

You also need to change the actual code for finding the names and telephones, but not by much. All you need to do is drop the `print(listToString(names))` and change the `print(listToString(mobiles))` to `print(listToString(names, mobiles))`.

The code should end up looking like this:

```py
def listToString(lst1, lst2):
    result = [None]*(len(lst1)+len(lst2))
    result[::2] = lst1
    result[1::2] = lst2

    str1 = "" 
    
    for ele in result: 
        str1 += ele + "\n\n"  
    
    return str1

elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='showLink reveal']")
for element in elem:
    element.click()

name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
names = [elem.get_attribute('innerHTML') for elem in name]

mobile = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@style='display:inline']")
mobiles = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in mobile]

print(listToString(names, mobiles))
```

This gives me an output of:

```py
name: xyz

tel: +12345678910

name: xyz

tel: +12345678910

name: xyz

tel: +12345678910
```

If you don't want the gaps, then remove the `"\n\n"` in the `listToString` function.

**EDIT:**

```py
def listToString(lst1, lst2):
    for i in range(0, len(lst2)):
        lst2[i] = lst2[i] + "\n" + "—" * 20
        
    result = [None]*(len(lst1)+len(lst2))
    result[::2] = lst1
    result[1::2] = lst2

    str1 = "" 
    
    for ele in result: 
        str1 += ele + "\n"
    
    return str1
```

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. How can I add horizontal lines instead of gap under every tel?

Comment: Change the line `str1 += ele + "\n\n"  ` to `str1 += ele + "\n" + "—" * 20 + "\n"`. Replace the `20` with however long you want.

Comment: Thank you, but this is adding horizontal lines after name too. Can I add just after every tel somehow?

Comment: Now I'm struggling with another problem this will be the last part of the script. I opened another thread for that. Can you check it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841915/selenium-attempt-to-assign-sequence-of-size-20-to-extended-slice-of-size-18