# Selenium attempt to assign sequence of size 20 to extended slice of size 18

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape datas from a website (names & telephone numbers) which have a pagination ... This code works very well but when the code reach a certain page number (for ex.: page 9) then I get an error:

```
attempt to assign sequence of size 20 to extended slice of size 18
```

--- full code ---

```
def append_new_line(file_name, text_to_append):
    with open(file_name, "a+") as file_object:
        file_object.seek(0)
        data = file_object.read(100)
        if len(data) > 0:
            file_object.write("\n")
        file_object.write(text_to_append)

def listToString(lst1, lst2):
    result = [None]*(len(lst1)+len(lst2))
    result[::2] = lst1 #this is throwing the error (Selenium attempt to assign sequence of size 20 to extended slice of size 18)
    result[1::2] = lst2

    str1 = "" 
    
    for ele in result: 
        str1 += ele + "\n\n"
    
    return str1


while True:
    try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='showLink reveal']")
        elem.click()
        name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']")
        names = [elem.get_attribute('innerHTML') for elem in name]
        mobile = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@style='display:inline']")
        mobiles = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in mobile]
        print(listToString(names, mobiles))
        append_new_line('datas.txt', listToString(names, mobiles))
        time.sleep(2)
        next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[aria-label='Next']")
        next.click()
        print(listToString(names, mobiles))
        append_new_line('datas.txt', listToString(names, mobiles))

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Not found")
```

Maybe I need to specify the range for the lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the function of `result` is to produce an alternating list from lst1 and lst2. I'm not sure if this would work but you can try to change the way that an alternating list is created. For example, in the function `listToString`, try changing result to this:

```py
result = [sub[item] for item in range(len(lst2)) for sub in [lst1, lst2]]
```

or to:

```py
result = [item for pair in zip(lst1, lst2 + [0]) for item in pair]
```

or to:

```py
result = sum(map(list, zip(lst1, lst2)), [])
```

Each of these methods do the same thing as:

```py
esult = [None]*(len(lst1)+len(lst2))
    result[::2] = lst1
    result[1::2] = lst2
```

By changing it to any of the other methods, it will probably fix the error.